# Django template - for with index

Tags: python, django

How can I use 'indexing' for in template?

I have this:

```
x=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

And in python I do this:

```
for i in x:
    for j in range(0,3):
        print i[j]
```

Then I get:
1
2
3
4
5
6

How use this in template?

Comment: With your code you don't get `1 2 3 4 5 6` but you get `1 2 IndexError: list index out of range` … Also: Why not use a generic for all the way? `for i in x: for j in i: print(j)` gives you `1 2 3 4 5 6` too.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Christopher!

```
{%for i in x%}
    <tr>
        {%for j in i%}
        <td>{{j}}</td>
        {%endfor%}
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
```